# ipcProviderBackend - Send request failed TypeError: Cannot read property 'contractAddress' of null

Tags: mist

I am using mist to connect to private blockchain and i get this error continuously in the terminal.

```
[2018-04-04 14:08:45.452] [ERROR] ipcProviderBackend - Send request failed TypeError: Cannot read property 'contractAddress' of null
at /opt/Mist/resources/app.asar/modules/ipc/methods/eth_getTransactionReceipt.js:29:34
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at step (/opt/Mist/resources/app.asar/modules/ipc/methods/eth_getTransactionReceipt.js:3:191)
at /opt/Mist/resources/app.asar/modules/ipc/methods/eth_getTransactionReceipt.js:3:361
at <anonymous>
```

can someone help me understand why i get this error.

Thanks

Comment: Getting this error as well, I'm curious if it's the cause of some other issues in testing my dapp